# Oracle 11g Count query slowness

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have written one query which provides me a count of item type using group by.
The select query if I fire without group up and count provides results in less than a second on sql developer.

However count query runs for ever that I have to kill the process.

Below is the query ..

```
 WITH permList
     AS (SELECT user_perm_level,
                item_category,
                active
         FROM   usr_perm_levels
         WHERE  usr_pk = '7'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT home_key,
                'ALL',
                0
         FROM   user_home_list
         WHERE  usr_pk = 7
         UNION ALL
         SELECT home_key,
                'UYT',
                0
         FROM   user_home_list
         WHERE  usr_pk = 7
         UNION ALL
         SELECT home_key,
                'ABR',
                0
         FROM   user_home_list
         WHERE  usr_pk = 7),
     list1
     AS (SELECT a.parent_home_key,
                b.item_category
         FROM   user_hier a
                INNER JOIN indhome b
                        ON a.child_home_key = b.user_perm_level),
     list2
     AS ((SELECT oh.child_home_key,
                 u.item_category
          FROM   indhome U
                 INNER JOIN user_hier oh
                         ON u.user_perm_level = oh.parent_home_key
                            AND u.active = 1)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT user_perm_level,
                item_category
         FROM   indhome)
SELECT type,
       Count(*)
FROM   inventory 
WHERE  is_available = 0
       AND active = 1
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 0
                   FROM   inventory_auth c
                   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 0
                                  FROM   orglist1
                                  WHERE  c.user_perm_level = orglist1.parent_home_key
                                         AND c.item_category =
                                             orglist1.item_category
                                         AND c.active = 1)
                           OR EXISTS (SELECT 0
                                      FROM   orglist2
                                      WHERE  c.user_perm_level = orglist2.child_home_key
                                             AND c.item_category =
                                                 orglist2.item_category)
                              AND inventory.item_key = c.item_key
                              AND inventory.item_category = c.item_category)
GROUP  BY type;
```

In explain plan I see that Cost of group by clause is 145297221173.

Now here inventory table has 10 million records and the exists block which works around inventory table also runs into 15 million records.
Where as views permList, list1 and list2 have records only in 100s.

I have tried various combination but none of them seems to bring better performance. Such as I have tried inner join between inventory and inner query with exists clause but that doesn't help much.

Comment: `provides results in less than a second on sql developer` is that when you retrieve all rows, or just the first N rows? A count will have to go through all the rows to get a result, not just look at the first few rows...

Comment: (inventory.item_key, inventory.item_category)  are collectively unique keys and have been indexed. Index type is NORMAL.

Comment: query didn't have any rownum clause, unless SQL Developer changes something there internally.

Comment: SQL Developer, like most GUIs will only pull a certain amount of rows across at a time. So, in order to fetch all the rows, you have to explicitly tell SQL Developer to do that. There will be a setting that controls how many rows it pulls across in one go.